# Using which method in WebAPI for SignalR in this case

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, signalr, signalr.client

I understand the differences of Post(Add) and Put(Update) in  Web Api. However, which one should I use in SignalR. When I am developing a Chat App

That is Hub Class

```
 public class ChatHub : Hub
 {
    ....
 }
```

That is ApiController Class

```
public class ChatClientController : ApiController
{
   // [HttpPost] or [HttpPut]??
    public bool Connect(ChatConnectionViewModel model)
    {
        //connection method
    }

   //[HttpPost] or [HttpPut] ??
    public bool SendTextMessage(MessageViewModel model)
    {
        //send message method
    }
}
```

My Question is:
1. When Client Side send a web api request to call Connect method, which request method should I use? **Post** or **Put**?

2. When Client Side send a web api request to call SendTextMessagemethod, which request method should I use? **Post** or **Put**?

**In addition**

My goal is to send Image file via SignalR. I just got an idea from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304673/signalr-chat-application-sending-images), so I am using signalR via Web Api. Any answers?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you bridging client with SignalR via WebAPI? SignalR is a technology in its own and should not follow the concept of traditional HTTP request/response.

Comment: Yes, I am bridging Client with SignalR via WebApi. I know SignalR have its own technology. In fact, my aim is to  send Image via SignalR. I just got an idea from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304673/signalr-chat-application-sending-images), so I am using signalR via Web Api

Comment: The approved answer in that thread said that you would need to use WebApi *separately* to upload image. So if you are following their approach, your webApi action will be a normal `post`, which before finishes, notifies the `ChatHub` (using this technique http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12188029/how-do-i-send-messages-from-server-to-client-using-signalr-hubs) to 'officially' tell client that the image upload is done.

Comment: You shouldn't upload the image using SignalR, but rather upload it the WebApi way and notify the needed users using SignalR. It is closer to the way it was built.

Comment: @radu-matei  Thank you. I have already done this way. but which HTTP request do you use in uploading  the image.

Comment: @radu-matei I meaned when you send an image in chat App, which method reques do you use? post or put?  And, when you send a message  in your chat system, which one do you use? post or put?