# How to upload image in azure blob with SignalR

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, azure-storage, signalr.net-client

I am working on chat application how to upload and recieve image to azure blob with signalR.  Is there any other service better then SignalR for image upload to blob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could upload the image files to an azure blob container, then from the server side send the direct blob's URI to the clients. I'd recommend checking the following thread: **[SignalR chat application sending images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24304673/signalr-chat-application-sending-images)**

Comment: I am successfully send image to blob but now how i send the blob uri to client.

Comment: Refer to the following link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name you can customize the blob uri

Comment: @Parmendra refer to this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-custom-domain-name it allows you to customize the blob name. Please upvote or mark as answer if answer was helpful to you. This would help future users looking for similar answers. Thanks

Comment: I have upload image to blob by:  
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
                    file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                    file.Dispose();
                    // return memoryStream.ToArray();
                    uploadedFilename = await AzureStorage.UploadFileAsync(ContainerType.Image, new MemoryStream(memoryStream.ToArray()));
                    activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
                }

Comment: Recieved: 
 var imageData = await AzureStorage.GetFileAsync(ContainerType.Image, uploadedFilename);var img = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageData));